# Get e-sign from echosign widget

Tags: echosign

I have added echosign widget in my site. I want to save the e-sign in my database. How can i do this?

As this is a widget it only contains on iframe. that's why i can't find anything to try it.

I want to save the e-sign when a user will click on "click to e-sign" button. Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a widget you must be having a widget id as well.
You can use the apis to extract signature form data and then store it in your database.

API for extract form data from widget (https://secure.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v2;jsessionid=34BFBC3886E48E109EB7A36CDB9E91CD.ord-prod-app15#!/widgets/_get_7)